# CreateDbCommandDefinition in the custom DbProviderServices not called?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I need to intercept the call to the following method of `DbProviderServices`:

```
DbCommandDefinition CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree)
```

So I need to create a custom `DbProviderServices`, here it wraps the default `SqlProviderServices` and forwards the method calls inside (because `SqlProviderServices` is sealed). It looks something like this:

```
public class CustomDbProviderServices : DbProviderServices
{
    static readonly CustomDbProviderServices _instance = new CustomDbProviderServices();        
    static readonly SqlProviderServices _sqlProviderServices = SqlProviderServices.Instance;
    public static CustomDbProviderServices Instance => _instance;

    //other methods ...
}
```

I can confirm that the custom `DbProviderServices` is configured to replace the default one OK. Because I can see the code triggered in this overridden `GetService` method:

```
//_sqlProviderServices is the wrapped SqlProviderServices
public override object GetService(Type type, object key)
{
   //execution can hit in here
   return _sqlProviderServices.GetService(type, key);
}
```

But I've never seen a hit inside the following overridden method:

```
protected override DbCommandDefinition CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree)
{
    //forward call via the wrapped _sqlProviderServices
    ...
}
```

But somehow the queries run just fine without any error.
So it's strange. I cannot imagine how and why it does not call that method as if it was unused.
Could you think of any cause for this or it's just a normal behavior?
If it's normal, where could I intercept it to get a reference to the `DbCommandTree`?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's very weird to not call the overridden method of `CreateDbCommandDefinition` which looks likely that it should be called.

By debugging the source code of EF6, I can see that the actual `DbProviderServices` used by the code is `EntityProviderServices`, somehow at the time creating the command tree, that provider services is used instead of the custom one of mine.

Cannot explain this but looks like it's a change from EF5 -> EF6.
The code in my question should work in EF5 but looks like it's broken when moved to EF6.

**PS**: I know that EF6 is the past and is going to be obsolete soon, but there are still legacy projects to work on and that's my case.